# Acumatica Integration $Filter tag not working with New/Extended Endpoints with Get Request (tried with POSTMAN)

Tags: endpoint, acumatica-kb

I have created New (as well as) extended End Point for Bill Of Materials screen/module.  I want the endpoint to return a single BOMID details , while it is returning all the BOMID with details (when passed without $filter tag of it). When I have included $filter tag as specified in the Integration Document (Acumatica ERP_Integration Guide document) it returns error.

The POSTMAN URL is like ({AcumaticaBaseURL} + "/entity/" + {EndPointName} + "/" + {EndPointVersion} + "/" + {EntityName} + "/" $filter=BOMID eq '{valueofBomID}') which is as follows :

http://localhost/AcumaticaMfg21R2/entity/BOMEP/17.200.001/BOMEntity/$filter=BOMID eq '{valueofBomID}'

I have also tried passing the individual BOMID with the Body parameter in request as JSON, but that also is returning all the BOM details (without $filter tag).

Without the $filter it returns all the BOMID's present in the system; with $filter it returns an error.

Error Message included below:

{
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.",
"exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.FillEntityImplWithKeys(String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, String[] keys)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.FillEntityImplWithKeys(EntityImpl entity, String[] keys)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.CreateEntityFromKeys(String objectName, String idsString)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
}

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same with `18.200.001` version endpoint. Its working fine. Can you please try with `18.200.001` or `20.200.001` endpoint version?

please find the below screenshots.

Endpoint: `/entity/Test/18.200.001/BillOfMaterials/?$filter=BOMID eq 'BOM000001'`

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]